# C#: Programmatically save an edited excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to programmatically save an active workbook using C# but the changes aren't saved. I'm currently using the `Save` method because I want the file to be saved on the same location, without creating a new file with the same name and replace the already existing file (`SaveAs`).

Here is my code that I'm currently experimenting with,

```
public void Test()
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    if (xlApp == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Excel is not properly installed");
        return;
    }

    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    this.xlApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    int col = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < intVal.Count; i++)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[col, i] = "TEST";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(this.xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.FullName);

    this.xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
    //xlWorkBook.SaveAs(workbookPath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    //this.xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
    //xlApp.Quit();

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    //this.xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
}
```

This is a method the method I run in a main class.

Comment: Add a new line of code `xlApp.Application.Visible = true;` just after the `save` call to see if you are actually changing anything. btw, what is the value of `intVal.Count`? Does this line `xlWorkSheet.Cells[col, i] = "TEST";` executes?

Comment: this.xlApp.ActiveWorkbook is the same as xlWorkBook?

Comment: Because you seem to be saving something different then you are editing.

Comment: @SarveshMishra It does execute everything, but the strange thing is that it saves it in "My Documents" as a new file(named "WorkbookX", where X is a  number 1,2,3...n)  instead of the current file directory. 'intVal.Count' is the size of an array.

Comment: @EpicKip Hmm... I will try to find out what I'm saving and what I'm editing.

Comment: You declare a variable `xlApp` in your method, but then later use `this.xlApp`. Do you have an `xlApp` in a different scope? Remove `this` and see if it helps your problems.

Comment: @mrsundquist Very true! That was one factor that solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @EpicKip Indeed, I was editing a "new" workbook.

Comment: Glad I sent you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);
            xlSheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlSheets.get_Item(1);
```

I solved my problem. The first problem was that I used `this.xlApp` which is a variable outside the scope. The second problem was that I didn't assign `xlWorkBook` a workbook. Thank you for the help :)